# Uploading Folder Recursivly to Azure

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-data-lake

I am trying to upload bulk data to an Azure DataLake. Following the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-get-started-powershell) from Microsoft, and changing the command to:

```
Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path "C:\Users\me\DataFolder" -Destination $myrootdir\Raw
```

I can get all the files in the folder, but not any of the folders within it. I have tried adding '-r' to make it import recursivly, but this didn't work. I can't seem to find any supporting documentation describing how to do this. How can I upload a folder and all sub-folders and files?

Comment: does using the full `-Recurse` switch rather than `-r` work?

Comment: Yes! Thank you. Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to use the full `-Recurse` switch rather than `-r`, final string would look like:

`Import-AzureRmDataLakeStoreItem -AccountName $dataLakeStoreName -Path "C:\Users\me\DataFolder" -Recurse -Destination $myrootdir\Raw`